# Snowflake JDBC driver redirects the user to browser on every SAML connection just to display a message. Fixed in 3.6.7 and broken again in 3.12.8

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The nasty habit of redirecting a user to browser on every SAML connection established with displaying "Your identity was confirmed and propagated to Snowflake JDBC driver. You can close this window now and go back where you started from" was fixed (at least for our application environment) in the 3.6.7 driver. Starting with this driver version only the first connection did it while all the connections after the first one were established silently. Starting with 3.12.8 the dummy redirect is back again. In an application where connections are opened and closed time and again the redirect is very annoying.
Does anyone have any idea what is going on here and if there is a way to avoid it happening somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed again in 3.12.10:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/client-change-log-jdbc.html

Comment: As I already mentioned (and I checked it now again because of your comment) for me it was not fixed in 3.12.10. It is reproduced in my application with 3.12.10/11/12/13. And yet again as I switch back to 3.12.7 in the same instance of the application just to get sure that switching driver versions indeed changes the behaviour the recurrent redirect disappears. Then my case is maybe not exactly what was fixed. 
For starters the versions where it was fixed for me and then broken again may be telling something to a person like you with some close understanding of the history of changes.

Comment: And thanks a lot for the answer. We know now at least that there is really something you are aware of at Snowflake. Then there is a good chance that a source of the issue will be located at some point.

Comment: I'm not a software developer and was just trying to help based on what I read in the release notes.  I didn't see anywhere in your post that you had tried anything beyond 3.12.8, so felt it was worth noting.  Reporting bugs on Stackoverflow isn't really the most effective way to report them to Snowflake.  Have you looked at the github for the driver: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc or reported the issue to Snowflake support?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we go through our contacts at Snowflake as well. I have posted the question here just in case someone has a solution right away. 
I have tried maybe too much not to write more than needed here. This round of investigation has started when we were about to propose 3.12.12 as the latest verified by us Snowflake driver. I have added it to our list not expecting the issue fixed long ago to resurface but was notified by testers it is back. After that I played with different versions of the driver up to the latest one to figure out exact points where it was fixed and broken again.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake support has clarified it for me.
The ALLOW_ID_TOKEN account level parameter is what governs the caching since 3.12.8 (JDBC).
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#optional-using-connection-caching-to-minimize-the-number-of-prompts-for-authentication
Then we will just need to take that into account. It looks like we have no other option in our application rather than recommend our users to set it. We cannot do it on our own as it is an account level security setting that can be changed under AccountAdmin role only.